# Drupal asking to run updatedb on migration

Tags: 7, migrations

I'm seeing this first time in the last 3 years.

When I migrate both files and db from Ubuntu to Windows, Drupal status shows me that DB updates need to be applied(while it does not say in the Ubuntu).

I've done this migration(from production to dev) plenty of times. I've not changed any server settings too.

**What could be the reason of this?**

Here is output of "drush updatedb" on Windows:

```
$ drush updatedb
 File_entity  7102  Empty update function to trigger an entity cache rebuild.
 File_entity  7103  Empty update function.
 File_entity  7104  Assign view file permission when updating without the Media module.
 File_entity  7200  Create the {image_dimensions} database table.
 File_entity  7201  Add the {file_type}, {file_type_mimetypes} tables.
 File_entity  7202  Update empty {file_managed}.type records to 'undefined'.   Drupal 7.8 disallows empty string as the value for a bundle key, so update  empty {file_managed}.type records to
                    'undefined' instead.
 File_entity  7203  Update permission names.
 File_entity  7204  Add title and alt text to image file types.
 File_entity  7205  Fix broken indexes caused by incorrect index definitions in update 7201.
 File_entity  7206  Configure default pathauto variables if it is currently installed.
 File_entity  7207  Remove the administration files limit variable.
 File_entity  7208  Add expanded file type permissions to roles with existing file permissions.
 File_entity  7209  Remove the {file_type_streams} table if it exists.
 File_entity  7210  Merge MIME types into the {file_type} table.
 File_entity  7211  Create the {file_metadata} table.
 File_entity  7212  Migrate the image_dimensions table to the new file_metadata table.
 File_entity  7213  Update default alt text and title image field descriptions.
 File_entity  7214  Fix the default value in {file_managed}.type to match the field schema.
 File_entity  7215  Fix the {file_metadata}.fid schema.
Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y
Performed update: file_entity_update_7102                                                                                                                                                           [o

Performed update: file_entity_update_7103                                                                                                                                                           [o

Performed update: file_entity_update_7104                                                                                                                                                           [o

Performed update: file_entity_update_7200                                                                                                                                                           [o

Performed update: file_entity_update_7201                                                                                                                                                           [o

Performed update: file_entity_update_7202                                                                                                                                                           [o

Performed update: file_entity_update_7203                                                                                                                                                           [o

Table field_data_field_file_image_alt_text already exists.                                                                                                          [erro

Performed update: file_entity_update_7204                                                                                                                                                           [o

unlink(.drush/cache/default/6.0-commandfiles--040498bac6cee8819aecd116e7eb3446.cache): No such file or directory filesystem.inc:132                                                            [warnin

Unable to create u://.drush/cache/complete.                                                                                                                                                      [erro

Unable to create u://.drush/cache/complete.                                                                                                                                                      [erro

'all' cache was cleared in self                                                                                                                                                                [succes

Finished performing updates.                                                                                                                                                                        [o
```

After this the site (in which I could log in after migration) stops working with the message:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT COUNT(cid) FROM {comment} WHERE status = :status; Array ( [:status] => 0 ) in comment_count_unpublished() (line 315 of D:\anurag\htdocs\my\modules\comment\comment.module).
```

Comment: Do you drop and recreate the database before restoring? You should. If you are doing this already, it sounds like you are restoring an old copy of the database. Cross-check the schema_version for file_entity in the system table on both platforms: SELECT * FROM system where name = "file_entity".